# How to return values from a function and send to AJAX using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, function, codeigniter

When i click the button,am calling a function it will return some values.I need to get those values and send through AJAX using Jquery.

Give below the click button function.Inside this function am calling another function(here returning values i need to pass through ajax)

The problem is i cant able to send those values inside ajax.

Can anyone plz help me to do this?I dont know where am doing mistakes.

Here is the function am calling inside button click

Comment: Return values from which function ?

Comment: @Abdessamad Plz check my updated code..I have added function

Comment: @Abdessamad my aim is to send dates in one array and frequency in another array..then i can save to database table(two columns are date and frequency)

Comment: @Abdessamad For example if results are 12 rows then database rows will be 12rows this will save when button click or ajax call

Comment: @Abdessamad sir any idea about my question?

Comment: I don't know what do you want exactly !!

Comment: @Abdessamad Sir, i want to store in database table,The columns are Date and Frequency.You can see jsfiddle values with two columns Date and Frequency..I want to store that all row in database

Comment: @Abdessamad plz let me know if u didnt get me.Then i will show my database screen

Comment: @Abdessamad simple i need to  add multiple rows with the giving results (from the function) and add to database

Comment: @Abdessamad for example adding a multiple rows in  a table  and will save the table...it will  save all the data at one click right..Like the way i need to do

Comment: @Abdessamad Did u get my point sir?

Comment: @Abdessamad i want to store dataSetsave.push([treatment, date]) separate array within the ajax i need to pass

Comment: @Abdessamad treatment (12 rows) i need to save in database table column and at a same  time date also need to store (12 rows) as per the fiddle results

Answer (score 0):

in this eaxample i have send with the ajax request the name of the function that i want to use

```
let fd = new FormData();
fd.append('function_name', 'activity_submitted');


$.ajax({
    url: "activity_submitted.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: fd,
    complete: function (results) {
        try {
            var str = JSON.parse(results.responseText);
        }
        catch (e) {

        }});
```

in the PHP file (according to the $_REQUETS['function_name']) go to your function, the function will echo a JSON with the values that you want to send back

**$_REQUEST** is a super global variable which is widely used to collect data after submitting html forms.

```
           function activity_submitted() {
            .
            .
            .
            $res = array('articleid'=>$articleid);
           $resBack = (json_encode($res, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
           echo ($resBack); 


          }


        ?>
```

Comment: I have updated my controller function in php.Is that correct?

Comment: activity_submitted is a function not page..function loading are correct only

Comment: sir, in your code where u r calling my function??where u r getting function return values???this is my function saveschedule()

Comment: i dont need these values getcontractbranch_name, getcontractbranch_freq.I need values returning from the FUNCTION only...plz check jsfiddle..there i have mentioned returning values

Comment: i will try to help again dear friend :)

Comment: i have added another question plz check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57655134/how-to-split-array-and-save-to-database